# Eisenstein's criterion and polynomials of degree zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Is [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion) applicable for polynomials in $\mathbb Z[x]$ of degree zero? If $a \in \mathbb Z$, then it is irreducible for $a \ne \pm 1$, but then surely I can find a prime number dividing $a$, so that "$p$ does not divide $a_n$" is not fullfilled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the problem is that, in the formulation from wikipedia $a_n=a_0$ so that the conditions that $p\nmid a_n$ and $p\mid a_0$ are incompatible.

Note that Eisenstein's criterion is a sufficient condition, so in case where it is not applicable (like here) it simply tells you ... nothing.

Edit: Actually the exact way Wikipedia phrases it ($p\nmid a_i$ for $i\neq n$) it *would* work for polynomials of degree $0$. But of course this is because the author is implicitly assuming that $n>0$.

Comment: In this case for $a \in \mathbb Z$ if is easy to find some prime number $p$ that does not divide $a_n = a$ for $n = 0$, but if I get you right the Eisenstein cirterion implicitly assumes that $n > 0$, so there is no formulation for $n = 0$ that would be consistent with the formulation for $n > 0$?

Comment: No the eisenstein criterion is about polynomials, if you go through the proof you will see it relies crucially on the possible factorisations of the leading term and the implications this has on the constant term. There is no way to make sense of it in the case where the degree is $0$ and both terms coincide. (In fact, it becomes fishy as soon as the degree is $1$.)